# Adjust cell options such as fig.height in a single code chunk with R markdown or Quarto using results='asis'

Tags: r, plot, r-markdown, knitr, quarto

I find the `results = 'asis'` options within RMarkdown and quarto extremely useful when trying put a lot of dynamic content into .html outputs.  However, I am now in a situation where I have a for loop within a single cell and I would like to adjust some of the cell options within the for loop.  Specifically, I would like to adjust `fig.height`.

**This code creates the output I am trying to achieve** (it's an extremely simplified example).

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r}
library(ggplot2)
```

```{r echo = FALSE, fig.height=2}
ggplot(iris[iris$Species == 'setosa',], aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) + 
geom_point()
```

```{r echo = FALSE, fig.height=3.5}
ggplot(iris[iris$Species == 'versicolor',], aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) + 
geom_point()
```

```{r echo = FALSE, fig.height=5}
ggplot(iris[iris$Species == 'virginica',], aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) + 
geom_point()
```
````

**Question: How can I achieve the same output as the above code, but within a single code block that is using `results = 'asis'`** Below is starter code that does the 3 plots in a single block using `results = 'asis'` How can I edit the code below to make the plots different heights while retaining a single block of code with results = 'asis'?

````
```{r echo = FALSE, results ='asis'}
library(ggplot2)
for(Species in levels(iris$Species)){
  cat('\n#', Species, '\n')
  p <- ggplot(iris[iris$Species == Species,], aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) +
    geom_point()
  print(p)
  cat('\n')
}
```
````